# rails params[:controller] vs controller.controller_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm just curious about the correct usage of params[:controller] and controller.controller_name as I'm looking for a way to get the current controller of a view for example but I'm not sure which is correct, I mean if there is something different on performance at using one or another.

Comment: What are you doing with that information?  Why do you feel you need it?

Comment: I personally would use `params[:controller]` and think this is the accepted approach.  @Makoto this is not so unusual - in my use case, for instance, I use this in my application layout to exclude certain pages from Google indexing.

Answer (score 2):

On Rails 4.2.5 at least, controller_name and params[:controller] are NOT equivalent.

If you have a controller in a subdirectory of app/controllers, controller_name does not include the directory. For example, say you have app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb (class Admin::UsersController), you will get this:

```
params[:controller] => 'admin/users'
controller_name => 'users'
```

Here's the method definition from actionpack-4.2.5:

```
def self.controller_name
  @controller_name ||= name.demodulize.sub(/Controller$/, '').underscore
end
```

The `name.demodulize` is the culprit here.

Answer (score 0):

I would say using `controller_name` in your views is a bit better since you are using a named helper which will emit a depeachiation notice if it is due to be removed from Rails. `params[:controller]` is tightly coupled to implementation and will not.

Comment: Even though in reality its pretty unlikely that Rails will ever remove the controller key from the params hash.

Comment: From the [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#routing-parameters): `The params hash will always contain the :controller and :action keys, but you should use the methods controller_name and action_name instead to access these values.`